# Different settings for gitlab and registry nginx

Tags: nginx, gitlab

I have a self-managed Docker-based Gitlab installation for which I need to differentiate access to gitlab site and registry according to source IP.
I've configured gitlab to listen to git.mydomain.com and gitlab registry to listen on registry.mydomain.it, and it works.
I want to restrict access to git.mydomain.com only from my public IP, and access to registry.mydomain.com from everywhere.

I've setup gitlab.rb with the following directives:
`nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "\ninclude /etc/gitlab/nginx_gitlab_acl.conf;\n" registry_nginx['custom_gitlab_server_config'] = "include /etc/gitlab/nginx_registry_acl.conf;"` 
in which I specify nginx acl (allow/deny)
Upon gitlab-ctl reconfigure, the acl files are correctly included in  /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-http.conf and /var/opt/gitlab/nginx/conf/gitlab-registry.conf.
However, when trying e.g. a Docker login, the acl of git.mydomain.com are used, resulting in a forbidden.

what am I doing wrong?